# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, cv2

PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.4 ругается, что не установлен модуль 'cv2'

Вот программа:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

SCREEN_SIZE = (1920, 1080)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")

out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (SCREEN_SIZE))

while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    frame = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow("screenshot", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

Но при вызове этого модуля напрямую через питон (через терминал), то оказывается он есть и даже версию говорит...

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
4.6.0
>>>
```

В чем может быть проблема?..

Comment: В чём задача, что не выхлдит  ?

Comment: Просто не запускается программа. Выдает ошибку, которая в шапке ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2', что нет такого модуля, хотя через консоль питона проверяю, он есть

Comment: Выберите в `PyCharm` то же окружение питона, в которое вы ставили `cv2`. Там где-то на рамке редактора (внизу обычно бывает) должна показываться версия выбранного окружения.

Comment: Окружение я создавал вручную после этого добавлял туда модули и только после этого создал проект. Сейчас ошибка ушла, после перезагрузки пк...... но появилась новая ошибка Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Python Projects\Запись с экрана 2\запись.py", line 12, in <module>
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: File "J:\Python Projects\Запись с экрана 2\my-venv\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 144, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.

Comment: попробуйте удалить и установить модуль , либо попробуйте более старую версию модуля установить